# Get qualification based on attribute value of array object

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to get the sum of qualifications based on the value of an attribute (idInteraction). How should I iterate?

I have tried to iterate based on abilityOrder but I can't match the idInteraction.

```
var arrayQ = [
    '{"idInteraction":"{9ae8653e-99ef-11e9-9e08-90c283d38b9a}","abilityOrder":1, "qualification":40}',
    '{"idInteraction":"{9ae8653e-99ef-11e9-9e08-90c283d38b9a}","abilityOrder":2, "qualification":60}', 
    '{"idInteraction":"{8ae8653e-99ef-11e9-9e08-90c283d38b9a}","abilityOrder":1, "qualification":20}', 
    '{"idInteraction":"{8ae8653e-99ef-11e9-9e08-90c283d38b9a}","abilityOrder":2, "qualification":30}'
];

var q = 0;

function findMinMax(arr) {
    let min = JSON.parse(arr[0]).abilityOrder,
        max = JSON.parse(arr[0]).abilityOrder;
    for (let i = 1, len = arr.length; i < len; i++) {
        let v = JSON.parse(arr[i]).abilityOrder;
        min = (v < min) ? v : min;
        max = (v > max) ? v : max;
    }
    return [min, max];
}

var maxAbility = findMinMax(arrayQ);

arrayQ.forEach(function(result, index) {
    result = JSON.parse(result);

    let i = 0;
    if (i <= maxAbility[1] && result.idInteraction) {
        q = q + result.qualification;
        console.log('id..' + result.idInteraction + 'q..' + q);
        q = 0;
    }
});
```

The expected result is:

```
"idInteraction":"{9ae8653e-99ef-11e9-9e08-90c283d38b9a}" - q = 100
"idInteraction":"{8ae8653e-99ef-11e9-9e08-90c283d38b9a}" - q = 50
```

Any suggestion?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the TypeScript tag really relevant here?  This looks like just JavaScript code.  Does the result need to be strongly typed in some way?

Comment: What's the role of `i` in the final `forEach` callback? It always remains 0... Where did you declare `q`? What is its initial value? Where did you declare `result`? What is the meaning of these variables?

Comment: result is the element of array.
i is for iterate within of array

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use reduce to get the sum grouped by idInteraction value:

```js
const arrayQ = ['{"idInteraction":"{9ae8653e-99ef-11e9-9e08-90c283d38b9a}","abilityOrder":1, "qualification":40}', '{"idInteraction":"{9ae8653e-99ef-11e9-9e08-90c283d38b9a}","abilityOrder":2, "qualification":60}', '{"idInteraction":"{8ae8653e-99ef-11e9-9e08-90c283d38b9a}","abilityOrder":1, "qualification":20}', '{"idInteraction":"{8ae8653e-99ef-11e9-9e08-90c283d38b9a}","abilityOrder":2, "qualification":30}'];

const res = arrayQ.map(e => JSON.parse(e))
    .reduce((a, b) => a.set(b.idInteraction, ~~ a.get(b.idInteraction) + b.qualification), new Map);

console.log(res); // open the console. SO can't show Maps
console.log(Array.from(res));
```